# Как выбрать все элементы контейнера и прилепить им класс?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть контейнер, который выполняет функцию body. Как прилепить абсолютно всем элементам внутри этого контейнера класс?
У меня есть попытка написать скрипт, но выдает ошибки, не могу понять, в чем причина
Ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property", ругается на строку  `All.classList.add('mobile'),`

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container'),
        All = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');

console.log(All);

function addClass() {
    if (container.offsetWidth < 1270) {

    container.classList.add('mobile'),
    
    console.log('done');

    } else if (container.classList.contains('mobile')) {
        console.log('true'),

        All.classList.add('mobile'),

       console.log('added');

    };

    
};

let timerId = setInterval(() => addClass(), 500);

addClass();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**querySelectorAll** в отличии от **querySelector** возвращает не дом элемент а коллекцию(псевдомассив) дом элементов. Поэтому у нее нет метода **classList**. Нужно проитерировать ее и на каждый элемент повесить класс.
Например:

```
All.forEach(node => node.classList.add('mobile')),
```

Comment: Ну, классы добавились в итоге, но чудесная моя верстка улетела в космос и получилась шляпа....

Comment: А) если вам нужны все элементы в контейнере, то нужно и искать в контейнере, а не боди.
container.querySelectorAll('*');

Comment: я может не понимаю чего-то, у меня мозг уже утек совсем... Смотрите, происходит такая замечательная вещь у меня со страницей... В чем причина может быть? https://prnt.sc/vlh3kz

Comment: По скрину сложно анализировать верстку) Нужно код смотреть

Answer (score 0):

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container'),
        all = container.querySelectorAll('*');

[...all].forEach(element => element.classList.add('mobile'));
```